# InfoPath 2013 - Individual Default View for Create, Edit, and Delete

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-2013

In InfoPath 2010 there was a trivial manner to set the view called for an item based on the function desired, e.g. a separate view could be made for create, edit, and display and set as the default.

See here:
http://chanakyajayabalan.wordpress.com/2013/06/20/individual-newedit-and-display-forms-for-sharepoint-using-infopath-forms/

I cannot however find the equivalent for InfoPath 2013, nor am I able to locate the corresponding element via SharePoint Designer.

It also would appear that you cannot append the view to the URL in order to directly call a view.

Creating a rule for Form Load that detects some attribute of the call, and sets the view accordingly seems like another option, but I'm just not certain how to access the appropriate identifier.

Final resort would be to do away with the InfoPath form, and create/modify pages via Designer, but would rather avoid this if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Found the way around this is edit the page in SharePoint. You can't do it in SharePoint designer anymore.

Create your views in Infopath then publish. After for the form you want to change the view on, IE create new item or edit item. Once there choose edit page from the settings menu, then modify the Infopath web part to use the the view you want.

This will work for additional forms as well if you want to add custom actions to the list.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I ended up getting rid of the InfoPath forms, and using an override via jQuery as presented by [Mark Rackley](http://www.sharepointhillbilly.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=47).